# mysql client setting no-auto-rehash conflicting with mysqldump

Tags: config, mysql

Our database has many tables with many columns. It takes a long time for the commandline mysql client to connect unless I pass it `-A`. I'd rather not have to put that in every time, so I tried adding the my.cnf option `no-auto-rehash`.

That works great until I have to use mysqldump:

`mysqldump: unknown option '--no-auto-rehash'`

Apparently mysqldump uses the options in my.cnf's [client] section, even if there is a separate [mysqldump] section. Is there any way to use `no-auto-rehash` and still have a functional mysqldump? Is there a [no-really-just-the-mysql-client] section?

Thanks.

The same question was asked on the mysql forums with no response:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,583759,583760

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put `no-auto-rehash` option in the `[mysql]` section, instead of `[client]`

```
[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
```

In this case mysqldump is functional.

Comment: hmm... it doesn't work for me... no-auto-rehash is indeed in the [msyql] section but I still have the same issue

Comment: I have the same issue. Not helping with mysql 5.7

Answer (score 3):

I do this all the time:

```
[client]
compress
user=uuuuuuu
password=ppppppppp

[mysql]
prompt=\h\_\d>\_
no-auto-rehash

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=1G
```